# How do I pass in a nested model relationship via a form_for tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have a `Conversation` model which has an `initiator`, and a `recipient` attribute, both of which are `User` models.

When creating a `form_for @conversation` how do I pass along `@conversation.initiator = User.first` and `@conversation.recipient = User.third`?

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :initiator, foreign_key: :initiator_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations
end
```

Comment: you can pass this as a hidden_field_tag like <%= hidden_field_tag :initiator, User.first %>

Comment: @Navin, could you give an example on how to do this? There are other questions on SO that don't give a clear answer to this question and are unresolved.

Comment: create a simple form_for for your @conversation with its attributes then just add <%= hidden_field_tag :initiator, User.first %> tag under the form_for and you will get initiator in your param hash.

Comment: @Navin, okay, that worked, now how do I get through strong params:

`params.require(:initiator)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"#<User:0x007fe586ac7920>"=>""} permitted: false>`

Comment: don't do that, have you created  strong params: params.require for conversation, then in same hash just permit initiator and recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning:**

If you're making an actual messaging app, don't use the code as is.

Never allow users to manipulate sensitive data. In the example below, someone named Alice can edit the hidden field and inject Bob's id, thereby sending a message from Bob's account.

I actually fetched Alice's from devise's `current_user` helper, and used `pundit` to ensure authorization.

**Solution:**

Fixed it, turns out the `hidden_field` tag first param has to be a `@variable` written as a symbol (`:variable`), and the second has to be a `:attribute`

Then you can find it under `param[:variable] #> {attribute: value}`

IMHO this is a stupid and non-intuitive way of getting this done, but hey, it works. Then you can strong param it and load it up in a model.

Here's the code:

in my controller's `new` method:

```
# GET /conversations/new
def new
  @conversation = Conversation.new
  @initiator = User.first
  @recipient = User.second
end
```

Then in `new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @conversation do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= hidden_field :initiator, :id %>
  <%= hidden_field :recipient, :id %>

  <%= f.button 'Submit', class: 'btn-primary pull-right' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller's `create` method:

```
  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.new(conversation_params)

    @conversation.initiator = User.find_by(initiator_form_params)
    @conversation.recipient = User.find_by(recipient_from_params)

    if @conversation.save
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Conversation was successfully created.'
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Conversation was not sent!'
    end
  end
```

And create strong params

```
  private

    def conversation_from_params
      params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject)
    end

    def initiator_from_params
      params.require(:initiator).permit(:id)
    end

    def recipient_from_params
      params.require(:recipient).permit(:id)
    end
```

You're welcome, future me.

Comment: Keep in mind, a malicious user would be able to change the hidden input values and send something else back to your app. If you need to keep this secure, you should avoid passing the `initiator_id` and `recipient_id` to your form and back. Just merge them with your `conversation_params`. For example, in your `create` action: `@conversation = Conversation.new(conversation_params.merge({initiator_id: User.first.id, recipient_id: User.second.id}))`

Comment: @Teoulas you're right, and that's actually exactly what I do, but it was a little different from the original question so I skipped that part out. I also use `pundit` to authorize if the right user is creating this conversation. I should update the answer with this warning :)

Comment: Well, it's a matter of whether you trust your users or not. `pundit` won't ensure that they won't mess around with your hidden inputs.

Comment: @Teoulas: I design apps for people like myself. And I send weird inputs just to mess with apps. In my real app I don't really pass `initiator` via hidden fields at all, I fetch it from the user's session. Pundit just checks if the user allowed to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that any object of conversation will have initiator, and a recipient attributes, then it would go like following:

```
def new_form
    @conversation = Conversation.new(initiator: User.first, recipient: User.third)
end
```

Now your both values are available with your model object @conversation, which you can access anywhere in the form, like as follows:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @conversation do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :value => @conversation.initiator %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps you.